# Why is my "pressed" and/or "selected" button state lost when a dialog is opened?

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I have an activity with two buttons (on Xoom running 4.0.4).  I'm programmatically toggling their state via setPressed() when clicked.  I realize ToggleButton or RadioButton may be more appropriate but I can't get changes from our UX team.  The problem is, when I open a new Fragment (mine is still visible) and there is a network error, an AlertDialog is displayed and my "pressed" button state is lost (background color changes to "not pressed".)  If the dialog is never opened, the button state is fine (not lost).  Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Why not just set the desired background instead of manipulating their state?

Comment: I did that and it worked!  Thanks much.  The "Why not" as you probably know, is that I've invalidated the style selector that the UI guys wrote.  If they change the color of "pressed" my two buttons won't change and there'll be a (minor) style bug.  Alas, I'm going to use this solution :-)  Thanks again!

Comment: firstButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Transparent);
secondButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_sort_selected);

Answer (score 1):

While a `Dialog` is getting displayed the `Activity` that triggered it is in the background.  It doesn't make sense for a `Button` in a background activity to be in the `pressed` state. The `pressed` state indicates that the user is interacting with the `View` and a user can't interact with `Views` that are part of a background `Activity`

Comment: That makes sense but the onResume() method is not being triggered on the Activity with the two buttons (or I would just reset the button state/color there).  onResume() isn't called when the dialog is dismissed or when the 2nd fragment is finished.  Am I missing an "onForegrounded()" method or is there some other way to be notified that focus has returned?